MAX488ESA+ - Mixing Two Different Serial Streams on same chip
I'm working with a board using the MAX488ESA+ chip for RS-422 communications. The board leverages the full-duplex functionality for related TX and RX streams. From the datasheet, this is the intended use.
But for routing purposes, I need to use an unused output like to transmit data which does not pair with the receive line (that is, the streams are completely unrelated). The baud rates are planned equal.
I'm wondering about the effects of this, but I can't think of all of them. Is there any reason I couldn't mix them? More importantly, is there any good reason I shouldn't mix them? I fear data corruption and timing mismatch issues.

Can you draw a photo to be more clear what are you asking?

The MAX488 is just a level shifter with independent driver and receiver sections. The two sections do not care about data rate or protocol, so there's certainly no need for the two streams to be "related" in some way.

@DaveTweed Thank you for clarifying this. This is what I expected, but I didn't get much confirmation from the datasheet's application notes. I picked up on the independence from the pin descriptions, though.

@ghan.154 I only have some experience with RS-422, but I generally agree with Dave here. That said, and also because you should want to include larger problems that may be found in externalities such as cabling and/or layout, arranging for the specific testing of this use probably should be added to the project. A well-designed test should not be too difficult to arrange. If it succeeds, you have objective evidence to add to the notebook. If if fails, then you know more investigation is ahead. Put this test in front. Resolve it quickly.

@periblepsis That's my plan. Since the change I'm considering also requires software changes, I'm making a test for it and am prioritizing it.
